# user profile replace first name last name with custom values

Tags: user-meta, profiles

I have a custom registration form that includes billing information.
In this form, I am having a parent register their child.
The billing information users first name and last name are populating the WP profile default first name and last name.
I need the child's first name and last name to populate the WP profile default first name and last name fields.

I've been trying various approaches to this for a day and simply cannot get it to work.

Here is a code snippet form my full script:

```
function add_student_extra_meta( $insert_metas, $data, $action  ) {
    update_option('test_x_student_insert_metas',$insert_metas);
    update_option('test_x_student_insert_data',$data);
    update_option('test_x_student_insert_action',$action);
    $insert_metas['student_first_name'] = $data['student_first_name'];
    $insert_metas['student_last_name'] = $data['student_last_name'];
    return $insert_metas;
}
function x_enroll_child($parent_id){
    $name = get_user_meta( $parent_id, 'student_first_name', true );
    $last_name  = get_user_meta( $parent_id, 'student_last_name', true );
}
```

Any ideas how I can get the value of student_first_name and student_last_name to populate the WP default values?

Comment: I read over and over; I can't really understand. Do you mind rephrasing?

Comment: Your pretty late to the game, I resolved this myself a few days after my post here.

The solution was to move the update_options into the second function.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to move the `update_options` into the second function.